# Why does the size of buf changed to 1 from 4

Tags: c, types, ipc

I am developing an application in C. I write data from one process to another using pipe.
Processes are remote and process-1 writes variable sized data each time.
The process-1 writes buf (`char buf[4]`)of length 4. In process-2 , I read that data. Foe determining the size of the I have used the ioctl() function call.

```
while(read(to_child[0], &byte, 1) == 1)               // Read first byte as ioctl is not
        {                                             //blocking and then allocate the                                        
                fprintf(fp,"\n Inside teh if block"); // buffer size = count+1;                                       
                ioctl(to_child[0], FIONREAD, &count);                                        
                buf = malloc(count+1);                // count is 3 here                                       
                buf[0] = byte;                                                               
                read(to_child[0], buf+1, count);      // total length read is 4.                                       
        }                                          
  printf("count :%d, buf size: %d", count+1, strlen(buf));
```

Ioctl() function reads 4 bytes into another buf at process-2() (As exepected). But after this when I print the length of buffer using strlen() it gives the length as 1.

```
OUTPUT:
count:4 buf size: 1
```

What going wrong here? Am i doing wrong with data types of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` returns the length of c-style strings, i.e., a null terminated array of characters (and they only have one null byte at the end). If you are sending/receiving binary data, it will return the position of the first '0' byte. If you already know the size of the binary data you don't need to query it, perhaps you need a structure with data and length fields.

In your case you can just do `read(to_child[0], buf, 4) == 4` to make sure you receive 4 bytes per read. A quite meaningless example:

```
typedef struct { char data[4]; int cnt; }  Buffer;
Buffer buf;
while( (buf.cnt = read(to_child[0], buf.data, 4)) == 4) {
  fprintf(fp,"\n Inside teh if block");
    printf("buf size: %d", buf.cnt);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. For binary data how would i get total length of buffer?

Comment: You cannot really get the total length. As I explained above you need to keep track of it yourself.